# SP 2013 - Search Schema - People Result Query

Tags: 2013, search-results, query, schema

I added a field to "Manage User Properties" in user profile. The field name is Exclusion and it's boolean to exclude certain users from people search. I have a powershell that uses some logic and check this box for certain users. so far so good. also performed a full crawled

Now on the people search result "change query", i added Exclusion=0 and i dont get any result back. The query text looks like this {searchboxquery} Exclusion=0. How do I find out if this field has gone through total crawl.

Comment: Try with `Exclusion<>1` instead to filter out unchecked users

Comment: i tried bunch of variety including Exclusion<>1 and none is working.

Comment: Try People:Exclusion:0

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need put some values on that property in at least one user property.

After that you need Managed property for this.

Go to `http://YOURSITE/_layouts/15/listcrawledproperties.aspx?level=sitecol`
Under Filters, filter Category People. Find `Exclusion` and that crawled property must have Managed property. If you don't have managed property, you have to make one.

GO to `http://YOURSITE/_layouts/15/listmanagedproperties.aspx?level=sitecol` and create new managed property with name `Exclusion`. Create with Type=Yes/No, Searchable, Queryable, Retrievable. Under Mappings to crawled properties click Add a Mapping and find that crawled property (something like `People:Exclusion`).

After that run full crawl.

And there you have it.

**EDIT**

Add mappings to people item

```
\\YOURSEARCHSITE\_catalogs\masterpage\Display Templates\Search\Item_Person.html
```

In `Item_Person.html` find `ManagedPropertyMapping` and add your new column managed property name `,'Exclusion':'Exclusion'`

Comment: Yes, I do have the new field populated for given users. Managed metadata is created and mapped to people crawled property. also ran full crawl several times.

Comment: Try with Exclusion:0 or Exclusion:"0"

Comment: tried this as well but no luck.

Comment: Do I need to add the Metadata to the display template?

Comment: look at edited answer

Comment: I made a copy of the Item_Person.html and made the changes in the new display template "Custom_Item_Person.html" and created a new Result type and did not help. Also created result source but not working. hmm.